# Restoring from Backup error - cannot be saved to computer

Tags: iphone, backup, restore

I have all permissions organized and a single backup in the correct folder.  I have 23 GB of space.  I have an Iphone 4.  I recently synced it and updated to the latest IOS.  My contacts were lost, and I knew that Restoring from a backup could fix that and return my old contacts.  However, I am receiving a seemingly common error message that the backup could not be saved.  My USB is fine, my "Lockdown" folder is fixed according to the specifications on the apple support site.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This may also be a software issue, you can attempt getting your iPhone into DFU Mode in order to restore not only your contects...etc... but also reinstall iOS (as it may have installed incorrectly).

As it is stated at [this webpage](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode): 
"

> Entering DFU Mode (Official Instructions)

```
Plug your device into your computer.
Turn off the device.
Hold the Power button for 3 seconds
Hold the Home button without releasing the Power button for 10 seconds
Release the Power Button but keep holding the Home button
Keep holding the Home button until you are alerted by iTunes saying that it has detected a device in Recovery Mode
```

"

Then you should be able to click the restore button, and restore correctly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise attempting to backup all your data using [DiskAid](http://www.digidna.net/products/diskaid) (You can download it for free on an educational license).

The best course of action that might be to restore in iTunes and then restore your backup from DiskAid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an error about backing up during a restore process, this is due to iTunes making another (just-in-case) backup during the restore process. The first thing I would check is the available space on your primary hard drive.

Otherwise, Apple has a large list of permission issues and the like to check in this situation :)

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2529?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US